# About if questions in Research papers can be asked on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic

I am new to MathOverflow.

> I am a master of mathematics student.  I wanted to ask if questions  in research papers ( regarding what I am not able to understand in the paper ) can be asked on MathOverflow or they must be asked on Math Stack Exchange?

Can someone please tell

Comment: I have added the tag ([meta-tag:on-topic]), since the question is basically asking whether one specific type of questions is no topic or not. [math.se] is mentioned in the question - but I wasn't really sure whether to add the ([meta-tag:math-stackexchange]) tag or not.

Comment: It would probably depend on the type of difficulty you are encountering; side note: I would not say you "doubt" a result, but just that you request a clarification; the "doubt" suggests you think the result is wrong, which is something you would only want to state if you're really certain.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker I mean I have questions in proof or other articles within the question, I didn't mean that I am thinking that result is wrong.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think that some people often mean *question* when they say *doubt* - here is a related discussion at [math.meta.se]: [What exactly might non-native speakers mean by “doubt”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3200)

Comment: This usage of "doubt" is common in Indian English. In fact, you can find discussion of this in https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Perhaps you mean questions such as this one: [Can “doubt” sometimes mean “question”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429) (The other questions [linked to that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2429) seem related too.) Anyway, it seems that so far there were more comments about the linguistics and the formulation of the above post than about the actual question which is being asked. (I have to accept my share of the responsibility for that digression.)

Comment: In case of doubt about relevance to MO, I'd suggest to first post at MathSE, and post later here if you have no useful feedback. If you're confident enough that the question is research-level, you can also post directly on MO.

Comment: I would say if it is a well-formulated problem and you are sure it does not follow directly from a textbook reference, then it is on-topic here.

Comment: In spanish, for example, the noun "duda" (doubt) is often used as a synonym for "pregunta" (question). I supose that the same happens in other languages.

Comment: I was going to say, is Spanish the first language of the poster as you do not 'ask' doubts in English but you do in Spanish.

Comment: @Tom You don´t ask doubts in Spanish either. Sometimes when you say (in spanish) "I have a doubt" you mean "there is something I don´t understand" or "there is something I don´t know". Those instances of "I have a doubt" will almost certainly be followed by an actual question with the intention of resolving "the doubt".

Comment: I meant in the context of 'Si tienes alguna duda, preguntame', not literally 'to ask doubts', obviously you can't literally say 'preguntar dudas'.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd say that this is a bit of a grey area.  If you want to ask a question of this type then you should prepare it carefully: do your best to isolate the specific point that you are confused about, explain it carefully, make sure that you understand the definitions of all the ingredients, and so on.  If you cannot isolate a specific point of confusion, then this may not be a good question for MathOverflow.

Comment: I would also add that probably one should do their due diligence, by first contacting the authors to see if they can clarify the point.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I don't agree with that.  Certainly, if someone has difficulty with one of my papers then I would prefer for them to ask on MathOverflow rather than contacting me by email.  That way, other people may answer the question before I need to.  Moreover, the answer will be publicly visible and searchable, which would not be the case if it was given in private communication.

Comment: As an author, I'm the one who has the primary obligation to explain my own work. Also, from my experience on MathOverflow, when people ask questions about papers they are not the type of questions that others find useful, nor do people get stuck at the same place very often. So generally I disagree with your assessment, and would want the person to not clutter the internet with highly technical specific questions about a paper that the author is willing to answer.  [Also, if the author does feel it is a confusing point, then they can post the answer to their website.]